# What was the economic incentive for "redlining"?

Tags: economy, racism

"Redlining" was the practice in the USA during the Jim Crow era of mortgage companies not offering mortgages to black people. But if black people wanted to take out mortgages, it would seem that there would be money to be made by providing them. So why did redlining persist?

- Was there an actual economic issue with black people and mortgages, e.g. the racism of wider society meant a higher probability of default?
- Were the white company owners deliberately forgoing profit out of a sense of racial solidarity?
- Were they afraid of reprisals (e.g. violence or boycotts) by the wider white population?
- Or something else?

(I'm aware of the "contract for deed" system whereby black people could get loans for houses on very disadvantageous terms, including losing everything if you missed a single payment).

Comment: Not my DV, but it might be better on H.SE, unless you claims in persited to recent times. Anyhow, I'm not sure there's an "economic incentive" for racism. Economics assumes rational actors, but I'm not entirely convinced that cognitive model is suitable for racism... The latter Q would be suitable on econ.SE, in a more abstract setting.

Comment: [This paper](https://www.sas.rochester.edu/psc/clarke/214/Arrow98.pdf) of Arrow might be interesting; has a huge number of citations. "Presumably the population of employers is not uniform in
its discriminatory tastes. Then, under the usual assumption of constant (or increasing) returns to scale, competition would imply the elimination of all but the least
discriminatory employers. If there are any non-discriminatory employers, they
would drive out the others."

Comment: On the flip side, he seems to have more Qs than answers: "Finally, what can market-based theories make of discrimination against black consumers? Sellers of houses and mortgages have refused to sell to black customers and
still refuse to some extent. It is hard to think of any market–based explanation for
refusal to sell. Sellers of automobiles sell to black customers only at higher prices. Why
does not competition prevent this discrimination, according to well-known arguments?" Yeah, econ.SE is probably the best venue.

Comment: If you post on econ.SE, it's probably best to tag with 'behavioral economics' as that's the more recent branch that deal with not entirely rational actors (although with limited success). A quick search finds some attempts of BE to treat racism https://issuu.com/peokeefe/docs/dismalscientist2020ii/s/10781198

Comment: Even though the after-effects of redlining are still affecting people of color today, this is still not a question about contemporary politics. I will migrate it to history stack exchange.

Comment: **Redlining is not denying mortgages to black people** https://www.federalreservehistory.org/essays/redlining Redlining is denying people access to mortgages based on where they live. It was historically used to deny mortgages to black people - however it didn't exclude black people outside the redlined zones and it did exclude white people inside the redlined zones. That was the point. It was secondary racism.

Comment: Is it really "secondary" racism if your primary purpose is to exclude black people, and you do it in a way that doesn't *explicitly* delineate the fact that you're doing so? That sounds like primary racism to me.

Comment: @AmagicalFishy is it really racism at all if your primary purpose is to minimize risk? Bear in mind that forcing banks to lend to high risk borrowers gave us the subprime mortgage crisis. The way racism has been subtly redefined in recent years to mean any inequality of outcome is disingenuous.

Comment: @user2647513 Do you have any evidence of that? I've seen it alleged, but AIUI the subprime crisis was due to mortgage companies *choosing* to provide mortages that would never be repaid and then bundling them up and selling them on with financial engineering that let chunks be sold as "AAAA" based on bogus models of default probability. Laws prohibiting red-lining had nothing to do with it.

Comment: @user2647513 See here https://www.investopedia.com/articles/07/subprime-blame.asp by that well-known nest of socialists, Investopedia.

Comment: @PaulJohnson: The sub-prime crisis was caused largely by fraud having little to do with racial issues, and is irrelevant here.  In economic terms, however, rules which prohibited redlining effectively required people buying homes in lower-default-risk neighborhoods to subsidize the loans of people buying homes in what were (at least at the time) higher-default-risk neighborhoods.  Such subsidies may have paid long-term dividends by unwinding the "self-fulfilling prophesies" that were needlessly harming some neighborhoods, but at least in the short term they were forced subsidies.

Comment: @PaulJohnson: If one individual lender had been forced to finance properties at rates that ignored neighborhood risk factors, that lender would likely have been unable to compete effectively in low-risk neighborhoods, and couldn't profitably lend money at rates much below what was offered by other lenders in high-risk neighborhoods.  Thus, each individual lender would have had significant economic incentives to factor neighborhood into risk and rate calculations.

Comment: Despite some assertions above, racism and redlining were absolutely relevant factors in the subprime crisis, although just how central would be a valid question: https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2013-08-16/the-dramatic-racial-bias-of-subprime-lending-during-the-housing-boom

Comment: Technically, it's classism rather than racism.  But it can be hard to distinguish them when one race statistically tends to be much poorer than another.

Comment: If they deny mortgages because a neighbourhood is expected to become black, then did they also deny mortgages to black people for white neighbourhoods, as to reduce the risk af the neighbourhood becoming black?

Comment: @gerrit Yes, when they applied. But due to restrictive covenants and the racial bias of real estate agents it wouldn't generally get to the point of applying for mortgages. All of this is distinct from redlining itself.

Comment: @dan04 It's racism, in part because the federal policies behind it were explicitly racist as shown in my answer. Not to say that classism wasn't also relevant.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Existing answers are missing critical points. Linking redlining to Jim Crow may be misleading because it wasn't just a Southern thing. It was practiced throughout the United States, not just in those states where formal Jim Crow segregation existed.

It should also be made clear that the reason it's called redlining is that it refers to the red lines drawn on maps, identifying neighborhoods where mortgage lending was considered risky. So in other words, it's racial discrimination by neighborhood as opposed to just by applicant. White applicants were also denied credit due to redlining if they wanted to purchase in a neighborhood where minority populations were seen to be increasing. So the economic logic was all about projected long term housing values in an area. Declining housing values would magnify the risk faced by banks.

An important part of the incentive for this racial discrimination came from the explicit racism of federal housing policy before the 1960s. The US Federal Reserve has [a history page](https://www.federalreservehistory.org/essays/redlining) which explains the important role of the Federal Housing Administration (FHA) that insured a large share of mortgages:

> The FHA began redlining at the very beginning of its operations in 1934, as FHA staff concluded that no loan could be economically sound if the property was located in a neighborhood that was or could become populated by Black people, as property values might decline over the life of the 15- to 20-year loans they were attempting to standardize. For example, the FHA's 1938 Underwriting Manual emphasized the negative impact of "infiltration of inharmonious racial groups" on credit risk. To limit that risk, it recommended restrictive covenants that prohibit "the occupancy of properties except by the race for which they are intended," which had become increasingly common in the 1920s. For the next few decades, the FHA generally favored loans on new construction in suburban areas rather than urban areas with older housing stocks or Black residents.

That article includes an FHA map with redlining for Chicago in the 1930s:
[image: Redlined map of 1930s Chicago]

Comment: Also: due to the host of other racist policies present at all levels of government the redlined areas indeed tended to have worse price development than other places. So it (in part) became a self-fulfilling prophecy. The further denial of loans to improve those neighborhoods also meant that once established, going against redlining was indeed a financially bad choice

Comment: Sounds like making it illegal would have ironically helped enable gentrification.

Comment: Why couldn't the loan terms be changed so that the FHA loans would be "economically sound", or was it just a practical issue? I'm imagining a scenario where high-risk buyers must put down 50% of the purchase price instead of 5% - the bank loses nothing even if the property value falls by half and gets foreclosed upon. The implication seems to be that it's basically impossible to sell a profitable loan for an asset that's expected to decline in value, but why can't the lender adjust the terms until it *is* profitable? Is it that no one would accept such terms in practice?

Comment: @NuclearHoagie I suspect if you look at the data you'll find some of that happening. The result was that when black and brown people did manage to get mortgages, they paid a lot more for them.

Comment: @BrianZ That's sort of what I'm getting at. The bank can still stand to make money by offering outrageous loan terms, instead of offering no terms at all. There is *always* some deal that would make economic sense for the bank, even if that's with a 99% down payment, a 30% interest rate and 1-month term. I'm wondering if the terms that would make it worthwhile would run afoul of usury laws, or if they'd just never be accepted by another party. Redlining seems to imply there *is no amount of money* you could offer the bank to get a loan, but purely economically, there must be a "fair price".

Comment: @NuclearHoagie I'm not sure where you're getting this part from but it's not the case: "Redlining seems to imply there is no amount of money you could offer the bank to get a loan".

Comment: @BrianZ It's implied by the block quote -"*no loan could be economically sound* [meaning, regardless of terms] if the property was located in a neighborhood that was or could become populated by Black people". Either it's actually impossible for the banks to profit in redlined areas, or it is possible for them to profit and their motivations for redlining are non-economic. It's my understanding redlined areas were flat-out denied mortgages, not even offered bad terms.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie All these things happened. It depends which neighborhoods, banks, customers we're talking about. There are plenty of sources to look at if you want to dig deeper into the data. https://ncrc.org/redlining-score/

Answer (score 8):

For a *strictly* economic motivation, keep in mind that the Deep South during Jim Crow would have been prone to an aggressive version of 'white flight': whites moving out of areas that minorities were gaining footholds in, retreating to suburban or rural enclaves that were more racially homogenous. This would set up a damaging domino effect. Property values in these 'flight' areas would plummet; established mortgages would be abandoned, leaving the lender to foreclose on properties of much less value then their original selling price; foreclosed properties would be difficult to unload except to buyers with lower wealth and higher risks. Whatever a lender might gain by offering mortgages to minorities would be washed away as whites decided it was time to go, collapsing the housing market.

I'm not suggesting that redlining *was* a strictly economic consideration, or that the economic argument outlined above isn't intrinsically racist in its own right. but…

Comment: That's not redlining as such. The point of redlining was that even in majority black areas they couldn't get mortgages becausethose areas were outlined in red on the maps as undesirable.

Answer (score 5):

In the Southern USA, you have to remember that those responsible for Jim Crow discrimination *were* the white capitalist class who collectively were in a position to control banks and fund mortgages.

The economic issue for them was not necessarily the admittance of blacks into the capitalist class, but the maintenance of a system as a whole which was capable of coercing black agricultural workers to work on extremely poor terms (verging on slavery, even after it was officially outlawed).

The terms for blacks had to be poor, because the white farm owners were largely competing to export food to the old world, where there was already abundant land locally, good infrastructure, and white agricultural serfs on much better terms in life.

The relative strength of numbers between white bourgeoisie and black labourers meant that the bourgeoisie proper needed a solid praetorian guard of middle class owners to direct and oversee exploitation and to be willing to lay down their lives militarily in defending the status quo against rebellion.

The bourgeoisie needed also to attract and retain white settlers from the old world who were capable of agricultural management (because of the skills and culture they brought from the old world, and which was not yet endemic in the USA), and they needed a slave class who were deprived of confidence and entitlement to the maximum extent so as to be more inclined to submit.

In the counterfactual where racism did not exist and all were exposed to raw market forces, you would have the prospect of whites becoming immiserated to the point they risked falling economically into the lowest slave class (at which point they would either flee back to the old world, or they would become dangerous radicals rather than genuinely exploitable slaves, and they would frighten and radicalise other whites who feared the same fate), and you would have the prospect of blacks achieving ownership and management and therefore emboldening the rest to aspire to the same and resist their subjugation. You would also, quite simply, risk the whites and blacks uniting together against the bourgeoisie proper.

So for as long as the bourgeoisie of the Southern USA was dependent on the extreme exploitation of black agricultural labour for profit, it was in their interests to insulate whites generally from the risk of falling into a status that could only cause them to be more radical, and insulate blacks from events that could only increase their confidence to resist and rebel against their intense exploitation.

So both very rich whites and middle class whites were broadly in agreement that racism was in their economic interests. Their ability to cooperate to achieve their shared interest doesn't need detailed explanation.

In terms of why a white defector (potentially a rich one) could not simply set up a bank which lent to blacks, it would be because they not only risked conventional violence to their person and property (from well-motivated assailants who potentially had everything to lose), but they also would have faced social ostracism, trade boycotts, and hostile legislation from local lawmakers even, for engaging in activity that would radically undermine capitalist interests if allowed to proceed.

If as a defecting capitalist you wanted to do non-racist business, you'd just move north.

Comment: That's a very interesting analysis. I've seen similar elsewhere, and its what actually triggered me to ask this question. Where I have trouble is the idea that the white bourgeoisie worked this out, agreed on it as a plan, and also took measures to punish defectors. I find theories where individuals just take the path of least resistance to be more plausible. As we look with the benefit of hindsight the logic looks very obvious, but I bet it wasn't so obvious in the late 19th century. Or, ... did they? Were there pamphlets published at the time promoting this? Or is this just speculation?

Comment: @PaulJohnson, well it's quite obvious they were capable of organising to punish defectors. Moreover they didn't need a "plan" - what both rich and poorer whites had were intersecting (or at least overlapping) interests. They both profited from the exploitation of black labour, and from attracting continued settlement of whites with farm management skills. The rich also benefitted from the fealty of middle class whites, and the quid pro quo was reserved occupations for those whites and protection from market competition with blacks. (1/2)

Comment: You also find these things sometimes take on a life of their own. Even when the rich would prefer to ease divisions and reintroduce competition, they can face backlash from the well-organised, politically-conscious middle class who have spent all their lives in security and will blatantly suffer from reform, and who therefore act autonomously to resist those reforms. The rich help create racism for their own ends, but it then becomes their master. (2/2)

Comment: @PaulJohnson sorry but your takeaway is ridiculous to the point of sounding like a strawman. There doesn't need a plan. And (see my comment under Brian Z's answer) once established, redlining became self-reenforcing meaning that anyone violating it was likely to incur financial losses without any manual punishment being necessary. Most things under capitalism that are misconstrued as needing a conspiracy do not in any way need one because bad systems under this economic model are very frequently self-reenforcing

Comment: @Hobbamok, I think frequently, those analysing political behaviour assume that there must be explicit conspiracy (like contractual relations) between people. They often cannot comprehend that even autonomous individuals are capable of conceiving of their political interests, and are willing to act in furthering them on the assumption (with modest risk) that others with the same interests will also behave reciprocally. As a result of socialising together, people often become aware that others share their interests and are like minded about how to further them. (1/2)

Comment: When socialising, they may also discuss the structure of their political situation and consider the implications of non-cooperative 
or ruinously-competitive strategies. So although they do not (always) explicitly conspire to follow a course of action, their minds become aligned on the courses of action they do and do not wish to see prevail in their environment (and they become aware that the other knows the same information as themselves). When they then come to make an autonomous decision, they are more likely to try to coordinate their response for mutual benefit. (2/2).

Comment: @Steve  OK, I see now.

Comment: Thank you @Steve. You explanation is very eloquent, logical and easy to follow. Did you write this yourself or is this out of a book? It looks so well structured and elaborated, like it was taken straight out of a game theory textbook

Comment: @Hakaishin, I didn't read it in a book, no. I've probably become better at articulating the point over the years, but I remember broaching this point almost 20 years ago with someone in the context of non-competitive energy markets. Although there's a temptation to think there is a secret agreement in place, the reality is that company management simply perceives that they cannot win by competition (especially when regulators will not accept consolidation into monopoly), so they stop competing. (1/2)

Comment: What they do is test a willingness to reciprocate, by putting their prices up instead. If the other follows by increasing their price, then both have boosted profits with no competitive penalty. And they might repeat small variations in prices until they are sure that they are each acting in coordination. Then, without any activity that amounts to criminal conspiracy, they have achieved a meeting of minds about price-fixing. The idea is simple really - it's only hard to understand for economists proceeding from a homo economicus model of behaviour. (2/2)

Comment: Thinking more, I guess the essential point is that not only can price-setting itself act as a medium by which information can be signalled to other market players (in a small and well-watched market), but the reality is that various things (like the setting of prices) are generally controlled by relatively small groups of capitalist managers, and it isn't difficult for them to achieve (through ordinary networking) an alignment of mindset amongst themselves about non-competitive strategies which boost profits.

Comment: And if a truly innovative new comer can't be fought off, after enough time he simply joins the coordinating circle, instead of actually disrupting the target market.

Answer (score 3):

In many areas compacts or social norms prohibited selling homes to Black people; this was done because (broadly) racist whites did not want to live in neighborhoods alongside Black families or, more tangibly, have their children attend school alongside Black children.

As these compacts became legally unenforceable and/or norms disintegrated, there was a pattern where one home would be sold (often via subterfuge) to a Black family, and then there would be a flood of white families selling their homes at increasingly depressed prices; within a year or two the neighborhood might be 90% Black (with many homes converted to rental property) and sales prices might have dropped by 20% or more.

And it is not profitable to underwrite mortgages in neighborhoods with falling property values and, often, deteriorating municipal services, so banks rated neighborhoods by perceived value which often was simplified to "percent of Black residents."

(While this went hand in hand with Jim Crow segregation laws, redlining was practiced everywhere in the US, even by Federal agencies, not just in states with Jim Crow laws, and persisted even after those laws started being struck down. Redlining wasn't illegal until 1968.

> The FHA began redlining at the very beginning of its operations in 1934, as FHA staff concluded that no loan could be economically sound if the property was located in a neighborhood that was or could become populated by Black people, as property values might decline over the life of the 15- to 20-year loans they were attempting to standardize. -- [Federal Reserve](https://www.federalreservehistory.org/essays/redlining)

Even as of 2022 Black homeowners are twice as likely to default on their mortgages as white homeowners, (Atlanta Fed, [PDF](https://www.atlantafed.org/-/media/documents/research/publications/wp/2022/01/13/01--racial-disparities-in-mortgage-lending--new-evidence-based-on-processing-time/full-text.pdf))

Note:  In the US it is nearly impossible to disentangle the effects of racism and the effects of poverty.

Comment: The funny thing is, once a neighborhood is predominantly black and the damage is done, it would be economically sound to start lending again. That didn't happen though, did it?

Comment: Also, the economical response to (perceived or true) different risks for different groups of people, back then including groups of different skin color, would be to adapt the interest rate, not to stop lending.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Even today, Blacks are more likely to default on their mortgages than whites, and there was, in fact, a pattern in the early 2000s of steering Black applicants into higher interest and lower risk "predatory" mortgages of various types. But in earlier years the damage would be done by steering minorities into different types of financial instruments altogether, or simply by refusing to lend in their neighborhoods, rather than by adjusting interest rates by perceived risk.

Answer (score -1):

There's wouldn't have really been any economic incentive for racial discrimination. Unless the government compels discrimination based on skin color or ethnicity, businesses as a general rule are more than happy to serve anyone who pays them to. Redlining was government mandated.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You are completely ignoring the fact that once started, a redlined neighborhood would be in decline (at the least comparatively) because of a lack of investment meaning that anyone who would invest would see less returns (or more losses) than in other areas. Aka redlining created the economic incentive to continue redlining.

Comment: This is ahistorical; note that many of the anti-civil rights lawsuits were by businesses forced to serve black people. Businesses have often tried to maintain a exclusive clientele which historically often included a racial component. Businesses, sometimes organizationally, sometimes managerially, and sometimes at floor level, often judged people's wealth in part by their skin color.

Comment: This answer seems to be based on the (common) misconception that businesses operate "rationally" in the economic sense.

Comment: @gerrit, or to be more precise, the misconception that businesses are not controlled by owners whose political ideas are more about maximising the exploitation of the workforce class whilst maintaining sufficient political strength to continue doing so, not maximising the number of other exploiters they put out of business through earnest competition. It's still "rational in the economical sense" for the owner, because they get rich - it's liberal economics as an academic discipline which is in such poor shape that it cannot grasp this as "rational" behaviour amongst a class of owners.